# Remove the defines in this safeguard mutex example

Tags: c++, templates, mutex

-edit- i cant experiment ATM but will tonight. I am thinking maybe a typedef can be used to hold mut and can be used to declare a var. But my initial thought is typedefs don't play nice with templates so i'll have to check later tonight (for now, to class)

I was looking at [this piece of code shown below](http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/224701827?pgno=3) and i was wondering how it might be possible to implement without using defines.

Since I cant compile the code (i don't have any mutex/multithreading libs currently installed) i'll just look at the code and think it out.

It seems like one can completely implement `PROTECTED_WITH` by inheriting a template class. The problem is now `PROTECTED_MEMBER`. It uses a name with ## to create a variable. This isnt much of a problem because we create a class which holds the variable with the `()` operator to make it appear as a function. However accessing `is_held()` the problem as i would like not to pass `this` or `mut_` in.

My gut says with out of the box thinking its possible to solve this without defines and without passing in to each variable a this, function ptr or reference. I'll allow everyone to cheat and use c++0x features.

```
template<typename Mutex>
class TestableMutex {
public:
     void lock()      {  m.lock();  id = this_thread::get_id();  }
     void unlock()    {  id = 0;  m.unlock();  }
     bool try_lock()  {  bool b = m.try_lock();
                 if( b ) id = this_thread::get_id();
                 return b;  }
     bool is_held()    { return id == this_thread::get_id(); }
private:
     Mutex m;
     atomic<thread::id> id;
     // for recursive mutexes, add a count
};

#define PROTECTED_WITH(MutType)  \
     public:    void    lock()        {  mut_.lock();  } \
     public:    bool    try_lock()    {  return mut_.try_lock();  } \
     public:    void    unlock()      {  mut_.unlock();  } \
     private:    TestableMutex<MutType> mut_;
#define PROTECTED_MEMBER(Type,name) \
     public:    Type&   name()        { assert(mut_.is_held()); return name##_; } \
     private:    Type   name##_;

struct MyData {
     PROTECTED_WITH( some_mutex_type );
     PROTECTED_MEMBER( vector<int>, v );
     PROTECTED_MEMBER( Widget*, w );
};
```

Comment: the code doesn't really protect anything, and it doesn't seem to be exception safe. why do you want to clean up this? instead use some reasonable mutex class.

Comment: @Alf: Maybe you should read the article. In short it ensures that if i access any 'protected' members in the class it will check if the class mutex is locked. Otherwise it has an assert error. To lock it (not shown in the Q) you use lock_guard which locks when the function enters and unlock when it exits (safe through dtor).

Comment: @acidszmbie24: I did see the `assert`. It's not meaningful since the method hands out a direct reference. Making a member `protected` or `private` and handing out a direct reference (or pointer) is the kind of silly meaningless thing that an utter newbie does. I used the word "really" to guide you towards considering that, but you missed it. And no I'm not going to read that article; the code is horrible and meaningless.

Comment: I would not go as far as some of the exact statements, but @Alf P. is right, you cannot create a thread safe object if you hand references out. If the API is not thread safe (and this one isn't) there is no way of providing a thread safe implementation. (**NOTE**: I am amazed that Sutter has written that code... it reduces code at the cost of correctness, I have grown to expect more from him :))

Comment: @David @alf. hmm. I think i understand what your saying. Your saying what happens if you return the reference to a protected member? I can see its pretty safe as long as you stay within the block and i would make it so you can only lock/unlock with a scope guard however in most cases returning a reference is bad practice and tends to break a lot of things. Maybe you know a fix for that?

Comment: @David: What else do you see wrong? ha, yeah, i have high expectations of sutter however i read this as 'better then nothing' rather then 'completely safe' as he typically does. I can things go wrong if you intentionally call unlock when using a guard (which can be corrected). Although i cant see any loopholes other then that and now returning a reference.

Comment: @Alf: Do you know any safe thread safe implementation to use in place of mutexes? i never heard of any

Comment: @acidzombie: if you need a mutex then you need a mutex. it's not about mutex versus something else. it's about how you use that mutex.

Comment: @acidzombie: you mentioned Herb and so "forced" me to click on your lihk. Would I have written what I wrote if I knew that the author was Herb Sutter? I *hope* that I would, but I'm *afraid* that then I'd used much woolier expressions. Anyway, what the heck is going on? How could Herb write something like that, not to mention publish it? Did that American radio reverend have it right, and we're living out the end of days after judgement day, just waiting for the big cleanup in October? Anyway, that code is really bad.

Comment: @Alf: haha. Right i'm trying to find as many things wrong as possible. Really the only two problems i see is returning the reference outside of the function (causing the mutex to be unlocked thus unsafe) and calling .unlock() then proceed to use it in the same function. The former could happen accidentally the latter i hope no one ever does but can be prevented. What is wrong with it? is it really just the two i mentioned? I also notice the code is UNTESTED bc defines cant use templates due to `<>`. He mentions C++0x so i guess he means something like this should work in the future? edit lol+1

Comment: @acidzombie24: since you are looking at *think-out-of-the-box* solutions for multithreading, you can take a look at this [article](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403766) by Alexandrescu. I find it better than Sutter's approach (it is a different level), but it was also closer to a real solution... Most people did not like it, some because they did not even understand the article and thought that Alexandrescu misunderstood `volatile`, others because understanding it consider that the approach is sound but incomplete (lacks the appropriate granularity for the locks)

Comment: @David: I don't get it... this also returns ptr (instead of a ref). Isnt this the same problem? i might as well ping @alf. btw what was wrong with sutters correctness? i already mention the two problems i see (one is fixable, the other seems impossible to fix)

Comment: The main problem in Sutter's code is that you cannot write a thread safe object that may leak pointers or references into internal objects, that interface cannot be made thread safe, as users may as well lock, get the reference, unlock and access the object outside of the critical region. In Alexandrescu's case, access to the object is done through the `LockingPtr` that holds the lock (i.e. `lpBuf->begin()`). You can build a thread safe interface, and wrap it in that idiom, but Sutter's code is *building your interface* in a not-thread safe manner.

Comment: Of course, you can build a non-thread safe interface with Alexandrescu's approach too, but at least you have the possibility of doing it correctly. Imagine that you have an accessor for a field, your accessor can be implemented as `void readData( data& d ) { d = this->m_data; }` (note: copy is performed internally, no reference to `this->m_data;` is given to untrustworthy users!), or you can have the accessor as `data readData() { return this->m_data; }` that does not yield references either. This interface is thread safe, the one that Sutter forces you to use isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an explicit specialization containing `using` declarations to list the objects protected by the mutex. Then use a base class to "pass" the access out to the user via `operator->`, so `object->member` (with `object` *not* being a pointer) performs the mutex assertion.

This is easier done than said:

```
// Imagine that the members of this class must be locked by the mutex.
class a : public expose_locked_by_arrow< a > {
protected:
    int i;
    void f();
};

// Declare which members are conditionally locked. Pretty simple and idiomatic.
template<>
struct member_expose< a > : a {
    using a::i;
    using a::f;
};

#include <iostream>

// Access mutex-locked members with ->
int main() {
        a x;
        x->i = 5;
        a const y( x );
        std::cout << y->i << '\n';
}
```

The library code:

```
// This template is specialized for each mutex protection client.
template< class >
struct member_expose;

// Base class provides mutex; parameter is derived class (CRTP).
template< class c >
struct expose_locked_by_arrow {
    member_expose< c > *
    operator->() {
        assert ( expose_lock_mutex.is_held() );
        return static_cast< member_expose< c > * >( this );
    }

    member_expose< c > const *
    operator->() const {
        assert ( expose_lock_mutex.is_held() );
        return static_cast< member_expose< c > const * >( this );
    }

    expose_locked_by_arrow( mutex const &m = mutex() )
        : expose_lock_mutex( m ) {}

protected:
    mutex expose_lock_mutex;
};
```

[See it run](http://ideone.com/IEC8K).

Comment: How does that saying go. You sir have won the internet!

Comment: Thanks. My first instinct was to use a proxy object (Node and I actually talked a little before starting writing), but then I realized there was another way. Most things are easier than proxies ;v) .

Comment: This is great code. Lets see if i can wrap my mind around it. You have my struct code with all the lock sensitive members under protected so they are not accessible. You also have the under a specilization called member_expose. It uses the `using` keyword so i dont have to worry about them out of sync. Now i dont ever call member_expose and i dont need to. Since my class inherits from expose_locked_by_arrow which holds the mutex i need and gives me the -> overload which gives me the magic. The magic hurts my head

Comment: Yep, that's all there is to it. Of course, David and Alf have perfectly valid criticism. Be sure not to leak internal references; it might be best to use this mechanism only on member functions, not member objects.

Comment: The -> overload checks if the mutex is locked which is simple. However the next part i dont understand. It uses the said specialize member_expose which has my protected members as public. What i dont understand is it seems to return a COPY via static_cast however it still allows me to modify the member if it isnt a copy. But why isnt it modifying the copy which prevents me from changing it!? If i assign it to a variable i change the copy and not my struct. But why!? arent i getting a copy of my object? also i wonder how this solution fairs with complex classes. But this is fantastic.

Comment: Actually i realize i used `auto` instead of `auto&`. Now i see how it works and hurts my head less. I'm impressed.

Comment: I forgot to note that in the article and question it uses `vector<int>` as a protected member. That causes a compile error. With this solution it does not

Answer (score 1):

The `#define`s aren't providing any protection as such, rather they are just reducing the amount of typing you'd have to do (in turn, they make sure all the "protected" members have the proper code in place).

There isn't a way that I am aware of to avoid having to put the checks into each getter function - and locking the whole object, as they are returning references to data stored within the protected object.

If however, they could all be returned by value (or not returning anything at all), then you could use a container that locks everything using a proxy object, something like the following (this could probably be done better, i've just quickly hacked it together):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Mutex
{
    void lock()
    {
        std::cout << "Mutex::lock" << std::endl;
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        std::cout << "Mutex::unlock" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class Object>
class ThreadSafeObject
{
    mutable Mutex  d_mutex;
    Object         d_object;

  public:
    struct Proxy
    {
        mutable Mutex *d_mutex;
        Object        *d_object;

        Proxy(Mutex *mutex, Object *object)
        : d_mutex(mutex)
        , d_object(object)
        {
            d_mutex->lock();
        }

        Proxy(const Proxy& proxy)
        : d_mutex(proxy.d_mutex)
        , d_object(proxy.d_object)
        {
            proxy.d_mutex = NULL;
        }

        ~Proxy()
        {
            if (d_mutex)
            {
                d_mutex->unlock();
            }
        }

        Object *operator->()
        {
            return d_object;
        }
    };

    struct ConstProxy
    {
        mutable Mutex *d_mutex;
        const Object  *d_object;

        ConstProxy(Mutex *mutex, const Object *object)
        : d_mutex(mutex)
        , d_object(object)
        {
            d_mutex->lock();
        }

        ConstProxy(const ConstProxy& proxy)
        : d_mutex(proxy.d_mutex)
        , d_object(proxy.d_object)
        {
            proxy.d_mutex = NULL;
        }

        ~ConstProxy()
        {
            if (d_mutex)
            {
                d_mutex->unlock();
            }
        }

        const Object *operator->() const
        {
            return d_object;
        }
    };

    Proxy operator->()
    {
        return Proxy(&d_mutex, &d_object);
    }

    ConstProxy operator->() const
    {
        return ConstProxy(&d_mutex, &d_object);
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ThreadSafeObject<Foo> myFoo;
    myFoo->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Which uses the operator->() trick (*when operator-> doesnt reutrn a pointer type, the compiler will keep calling operator-> on the returned values until eventually a regular pointer type is returned*) and gives the following output:

```
Mutex::lock
Foo::foo
Mutex::unlock
```

Generally speaking though, an object that needs to be used by multiple threads shouldn't be exposing its internals like that, it would be safer to have it accept parameters and use its internal values to act on them.

Comment: I see what you did there but the biggest problem is each variable will have its own mutex rather then a shared mutex

Comment: No, you would put the whole `MyData` struct in there, so you would be using `ThreadSafeObject<MyData>` everywhere.  Assuming `MyData` follows standard thread-safety rules, such as not returning references to its members, I think it'd be ok.

Comment: ahh right. Good thought. Taking a quick sec to think it might cause the problem were if i declare the member inside a class it would be forever held. But i didnt look at your proxy in detail as i am in a bit of a rush. I'll definitely use this in my experiment but you did at least answer one way to get the #defines out. +1.

Comment: Yeah, the copying semantics are all wrong, you'd need to sort that out.

Comment: The type should probably not be copyable, but rather movable (which fits the *allow everyone to cheat and use c++0x features*)